# How to trim spaces between word, and after comma using javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following string called name and I want to trim spaces between words in a sentence and to trim space after comma also.
I am able to trim extra spaces using trim() at the begining and end of the sentence.
[I am using javascript to implement my code]

```
name = '      Barack Hussein       Obama II is an     American politician who served       as the 44th President        of the United States from January 20,    2009,    to January 20, 2017.
```

Expected Output:

```
name = ' Barack Hussein  Obama II is an American politician who served  as the 44th President of the United States from January 20, 2009, to January 20, 2017.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default string.replace in JavaScript will only replace the first matching value it finds, adding the /g will mean that all of the matching values are replaced.

The g regular expression modifier (called the global modifier) basically says to the engine not to stop parsing the string after the first match.

```
var string = "      Barack Hussein       Obama II is an     American politician who served       as the 44th President        of the United States from January 20,    2009,    to January 20, 2017."
alert(string)
string = string.replace(/ +/g, ' ');
alert(string)
```

A list of useful modifiers:

- g - Global replace. Replace all instances of the matched string in the provided text.
- i - Case insensitive replace. Replace all instances of the matched string, ignoring differences in case.
- m - Multi-line replace. The regular expression should be tested for matches over multiple lines.

You can combine modifiers, such as g and i together, to get a global case insensitive search.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that the remaining double-spaces are just a typo, you can use a regular expression to match one or more spaces, and replace each with a single space:

```js
const name1 = '      Barack Hussein       Obama II is an     American politician who served       as the 44th President        of the United States from January 20,    2009,    to January 20, 2017.';
console.log(
  name1.replace(/ +/g, ' ')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

In angularjs you can use `trim()` function

```
const nameStr = '      Barack Hussein       Obama II is an     American politician who served       as the 44th President        of the United States from January 20,    2009,    to January 20, 2017.';

console.log(nameStr.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim());
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let msg = '      Barack Hussein       Obama II is an     American politician who served       as the 44th President        of the United States from January 20,    2009,    to January 20, 2017.';

console.log(msg.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' '));
```